# Samesite issue in ios 12 browsers

Tags: ios12, samesite

I am facing an issue in online payment portal ,when redirecting from merchant portal the session gets timedout in ios 12 browsers, i suspect this due to Samesite attribute not applying properly, currently it has been applied in revreseproxy level,are there any solutions for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've provided some detail on this here: https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/#handling-incompatible-clients

The summary is that you can either:

1. Set the same data in two separate cookies:

```
Set-cookie: 3pcookie=value; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-cookie: 3pcookie-legacy=value; Secure
```

On the receiving end, you can then check which cookie has been received. If the
`legacy` cookie is present, then you know you are dealing with an older browser
and can adjust accordingly.

2. Detect the browser based on the `User-Agent` value. There's a regular expression you can use here: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients however any form of `User-Agent` detection will be fragile, so exercise caution.